# Total possible combinations of multiple different binary variable that are dependent on one another

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to figure out the total number of combinations possible where there are multiple sets of true/false questions. So for example, I have 12 sets of yes/no questions. So for combination one: first question answered yes, second answered no, third answered yes.... and so on. That is one set of combinations. Another set would have no for number one, yes for question two and three...etc.

Comment: How are these dependent on one another? Are you not free to choose exactly which option you like on each question? Or is that a typo in your title?

Answer (score 0):

Each question has one of 2 possible answers. Since the questions are ordered the combinations combine multiplicatively. Thus the number of combinations is $2^{12} = 4096$. This is assuming I understood your question correctly.